# postgresql query and db performence tuning

Tags: postgresql, query-performance, postgresql-9.6

We are getting slow performance while executing query

```
select count(*) from test;
```

It is taking 30 seconds. We have 470 columns in a table with few indexes and the table have 50 million records.

```
select distinct name1,name2,id 
from test 
where id in (1234,6543,7643,9876);
```

The above query is also taking above 5 minutes. Please suggest.

I configured parameters in `postgresql.conf` as shown below.

```
max_connections = 10 
shared_buffers = 4GB
effective_cache_size = 12GB
maintenance_work_mem = 1GB
checkpoint_completion_target = 0.7
wal_buffers = 16MB
default_statistics_target = 100
random_page_cost = 4
effective_io_concurrency = 2
work_mem = 419430kB
min_wal_size = 1GB
max_wal_size = 2GB
idle_in_transaction_session_timeout = 9000000
```

I am using PostgreSQL 9.6 and my server haas 16 GB ram

Can we create multiple columns on single index or separate indexes for single columns?

```
CREATE TABLE test (
    accept_dt timestamp NULL,
    test_line_number int4 NULL,
    office varchar(120) NULL,
    add_dt timestamp NULL,
    name1   int4 NULL,
    name2   int4 NULL,
    name3   int4 NULL,
    .....
    .....
    ....
    );

CREATE INDEX test_indx ON public.test USING btree (name1,name2,name3,name4);
CREATE INDEX test2_indx ON public. USING btree (accept_dt, test_line_number);
```

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the `create table` statements for the tables in question (including all indexes) and the [execution plan](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/using-explain.html) generated using **`explain (analyze, buffers)`** (not just a simple "explain"). [Formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: Unrelated to your performance problem: 420MB for work_mem is extremely high especially if you only have 16GB. Every query can allocate that amount of memory **multiple times**.

Comment: `We have 470 columns...` looks more like a spreadsheet to me...

Comment: Regarding your 2nd query (`select distinct name1,name2,id from test where id in (1234,6543,7643,9876)`), I don't see any index on `id`.